# PHP and MySQL migration to Azure

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I'm currently trying to migrate my website from its current hosting to Azure. I've successfully managed to move and configure everything to copy my code (we use GitHub so it's been pretty easy). I've linked the website to a MySQL database which seems to be hosted on clearDB. Everything seems to work fine, as I though when I saw it running (qwerteach.azurewebsites.net/index.php)

However, none of my INSERT queries will work as I get this:

> error1364: Field 'some-field' doesn't have a default value.

As I know my queries, this problem will be with most of them! It seems it is due to clearDB operating in strict mode, and from a first web search of the problem, that can't be changed? (I need confirmation on that one).

So, what do you think would be the best way to get my website running? Maybe I can migrate the database to Azure SQL? (would my queries work, then, or would I need to adapt them?)
Maybe I should just change all my INSERT queries straight?

Also, are there other constraints due to that strict operating mode that would need adapting?

Comment: Why you just assign a default NULL value?

Comment: So I need to edit my tables and add a default null value to all the fields?

Comment: Yeah to the fields that could be NULL

Comment: hand't thought of it, I feel stupid... Is there any way to automate it for all fields in a table? there might be a lot of fields and/or tables

Comment: Yes there sure is. Search for things like `SHOW TABLES`, `SHOW COLUMNS`,`ALTER TABLE` and combine that statements together.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've got it all solved now :)